# Staggered working hours

Tags: terminology

I work from 8 AM to 5 PM, but sometimes have to work from 10 AM to 6 PM instead. Some days my boss moves a shift from Tuesday to Saturday. What is the English term for this? Staggered (working) hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staggered shifts are usually when a company has people start at different times throughout the day for best performance, as opposed to everyone starting/finishing at the same time, so if that's the case with your job then staggered shifts are a good way to describe them.

If your company gives you the choice of starting at 10AM instead of 8AM it would be a flexi-start shift.

The shift your boss moves from Tuesday to Saturday could be known as a rotating shift, if it's done regularly and for business reasons, like to increase staffing at the end of the month for example. If it's not something that happens regularly, or done because of unexpected reasons it might be better called a cover shift.

Comment: This is a good first answer, but it could be improved with links to sources for your claims. If you click on the question mark in a circle at the top right of your screen, you can take a tour to learn more about this site (and pick up some bonus points for doing so). Welcome to EL&U!

Comment: Thank you! My boss could say we need one extra person working late one day. Can I still use *staggered hours* if I'm the only one who has to come in late?